# How to combine two RMarkdown (.Rmd) files into a single output?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

I have two files in the same folder: chapter1.Rmd and chapter2.Rmd, with the following content:

**chapter1.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Chapter 1"
output: pdf_document
---

## This is chapter 1. {#Chapter1}

Next up: [chapter 2](#Chapter2)
```

**chapter2.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Chapter 2"
output: pdf_document
---

## This is chapter 2. {#Chapter2}

Previously: [chapter 1](#Chapter1)
```

How can I knit these so that they combine into a single pdf output?

Of course, `render(input = "chapter1.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")` works perfectly but `render(input = "chapter1.Rmd", input = "chapter2.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")` does not.

Why do I want to do this? To break up a [giant document](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/spatial-microsim-book/blob/master/book-cambridge.Rmd) into logical files.

I've used @hadley 's [bookdown](https://github.com/hadley/bookdown) package to build latex from .Rmd but this seems like overkill for this particular task. Is there a simple solution using knitr/pandoc/linux command line I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just write natively in LaTeX? Seems like all the tools you need for this are built into LaTeX and the knitting process runs your document through a TeX engine anyway.

Comment: Yes I like latex and need to get into embedding code into it so that's a good plan B. Working on an R solution with read/writeLines function ATM because I believe Markdown is the user-friendly future! http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1894 I.e. it's a philosophical decision: be the change you want to see in the world.

Comment: Also, writing as markdown reduces the barrier to entry to contributing. Eventually it will be LaTeX, but for the time being markdown is sufficient.

Comment: hadley's bookdown is now being developed by @yihui and has had a lot of further work and useful documentation: http://rstudio.github.io/bookdown/

Answer (score 188, accepted):

> **August, 2018 update:** This answer was written before the advent of **bookdown**, which is a more powerful approach to writing Rmarkdown based books. Check out the minimal **bookdown** example in @Mikey-Harper's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51521542/7347699)!

When I want to break a large report into separate Rmd, I usually create a parent Rmd and include the chapters as children. This approach is easy for new users to understand, and if you include a table of contents (toc), it is easy to navigate between chapters.

**report.Rmd**

````
---  
title: My Report  
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes 
---

```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'chapter2.Rmd'}
```
````

**chapter1.Rmd**

````
# Chapter 1

This is chapter 1.

```{r}
1
```
````

**chapter2.Rmd**

````
# Chapter 2

This is chapter 2.

```{r}
2
```
````

**Build**

```
rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd')
```

Which produces:
[image: My report]

And if you want a quick way to create the chunks for your child documents:

````
rmd <- list.files(pattern = '*.Rmd', recursive = T)
chunks <- paste0("```{r child = '", rmd, "'}\n```\n")
cat(chunks, sep = '\n')
# ```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
# ```
#
# ```{r child = 'chapter2.Rmd'}
# ```
````

Comment: It works, yet i have 10 chapter. When i render the files, it goes up to 5th file. I can see all titles from PDF navigation panel but pages are not shown.

Answer (score 46):

I'd recommend that people use the **bookdown** package for creating reports from multiple R Markdown files. It adds a lot of useful features like cross-referencing which are very useful for longer documents.

Adapting the example from *@Eric*, here is a minimal example of the **bookdown** setup. The main detail is that the main file has to be called `index.Rmd` , and must include the additional YAML line `site: bookdown::bookdown_site`:

**index.Rmd**

```
---
title: "A Minimal bookdown document"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: yes
---
```

**01-intro.Rmd**:

````
# Chapter 1

This is chapter 1.

```{r}
1
```
````

**02-intro.Rmd**:

````
# Chapter 2

This is chapter 2.

```{r}
2
```
````

If we Knit the `index.Rmd` **bookdown** will merge all the files in the same directory in alphabetical order (this behaviour can be changed using an extra `_bookdown.yml` file).

[image]

Once you get comfortable with this basic setup, it is easy to customise the bookdown document and output formats using additional configuration files i.e. `_bookdown.yml` and `_output.yml`

> **Further Reading**
>
> - [R Markdown: The definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/books.html): Chapter 11 provides a great overview of bookdown
> - [Authoring books with bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) provides a comprehensive guide on bookdown, and recommended for more advanced details.

Comment: is it possible to render nested Rmd files this way? how? I would like to have single Rmd for each element in a _chapter_.

Comment: **bookdown** generally recommends each file contains one chapter. However, it should be possible to split into separate files if desired. The easiest way would be to provide each file with a numeric index such as 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 etc.

Comment: I was  trying to add appendix at the end which shows code for both document. How can i achieve ?

Comment: This seems like a distinct different question. You may want to open another question and provide a complete example which I will try my best to answer :)

Comment: Clarification: Knit only previews the current document, while "Build book" builds it all.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
Rmd_bind <- 
    function(dir = ".",
    book_header = readLines(textConnection("---\ntitle: 'Title'\n---")))
{
    old <- setwd(dir)
    if(length(grep("book.Rmd", list.files())) > 0){
    warning("book.Rmd already exists")
    }
    write(book_header, file = "book.Rmd", )
    cfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*.Rmd", )
    ttext <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(cfiles)){
    text <- readLines(cfiles[i])
    hspan <- grep("---", text)
    text <- text[-c(hspan[1]:hspan[2])]
    write(text, sep = "\n", file = "book.Rmd", append = T)
    }
    render("book.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")
    setwd(old)
    }
```

Imagine there's a better solution and would be nice to have something like this in rmarkdown or knitr packages.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable solution, except you forgot a few parentheses (and indentation!! :)