# rmd file too large to open

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have a 9.5 mb .rmd file, which I got from someone to finish a task. 
When I try to load the file in RStudio, it says the maximum size allowed is 5mb and it can not open the file.
Can anybody suggest a solution to it.

Comment: Richard's suggestion is fine, but you may want to take the opportunity to use something like Sublime Text 3 (with the R-Box add-on) and then use the `knitr` function calls directly to render the document to whatever the output form is. There may be good reasons to keep the Rmd source in a single, contiguous document and the R world doesn't revolve around RStudio (I :heart: those folks but also take great pains to ensure I can use R without it). Also, did you ask them how they created/edited it? They may be wiling to show you their setup.

Answer (score 0):

First open the file in a standard text editor and have a look why it is so large.

Maybe it contains data or code that can be moved to other files.

Else you could split the file into a parent and child files and have them rendered together. See [How to combine two RMarkdown (.Rmd) files into a single output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output)