# How to specify global chunk option in a rmarkdown website?

Tags: r, r-markdown, chunks

It is possible to create a [website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html) with several rmarkdown files. For each rmarkdown file, we can specify some global options like:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)
```
````

If I want to apply all these options to all rmd files, I can put the same code in each file.

I would like to know if it is possible to put this code somewhere so that it can be shared to every rmd files. In fact, sometimes, I want to make some change (for example set echo = TRUE), and I want to do it once for the entire website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two RMarkdown (.Rmd) files into a single output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include a child document

````
```{r, child="_setup.Rmd"}
```
````

at the beginning of each rmd file.