# Rendering multiple R scripts as markdown within single markdown file

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have several R scripts that are are documented using `#'` with the purpose of combining all the scripts into a single `.Rmd` file.

I saw from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output) that it's really straight forward to combine multiple `.Rmd` files using code chunks within the master `.Rmd` file

This is nice but I prefer to keep my code as `.R` files because it runs faster for its intended purpose and the rendering of the documentation will not happen as often.

First I tried this in the main markdown file:

````
```{r, child = "script.R"}
```
````

But that didn't render properly - bascally a bunch of markdown text with the `#'`s present.

Then I attempted to use what's described in this [**blog post**](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/render-reports-directly-from-R-scripts/) in order to combine the R scripts in a single markdown file:

````
```{r}
library(rmarkdown)
rmarkdown::render("script.R")
```
````

But this just produces `script.md` and does not embed the markdown into the main file. Any thoughts on how to correctly render the `.R` scripts as markdown within the main file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach. It will use `rmarkdown::render` to generate md file, and then read the content of the md file and incorporate it into the main file by setting the option `results` to `asis`. The drawback is the method generates some temporary files, and it may not be very performant but it achieves the goal.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Consistency"
date: "2017/6/29"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

join <- function(ls, sep = ", "){
    do.call(paste, append(ls, list(sep = sep)))
}

inline_render <- function(script_name){
    suppressMessages(capture.output(rmarkdown::render(paste0(script_name, ".R"), output_format = "rmarkdown::md_document"), file = "tmp"))
    cat(join(readLines(paste0(script_name, ".md")), "\n"))

}
```

```{r script, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
inline_render("script")
```

```{r script1, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
inline_render("script1")
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this works for me but it appears to make diagrams within my markdown stop displaying. Specifically diagrams created using `grViz()` function and the `diagrammeR` package

Comment: That is a somewhat unrelated problem. But one problem I'm encountering is when add other scripts is this error `Quitting from lines NA-87 (script2.spin.Rmd) 
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src) : 
  duplicate label 'unnamed-chunk-1'`

Comment: @Warner It seems that the second problem is caused by label conflict, so a solution is to label the code chunk, like in my edited answer.

Comment: @Warner Could you provide some mimic example of your `DiagrammeR` code so I can test with? Thx.

Comment: thanks I actually just discovered that solution. I appreciate you putting it in your answer. Regarding my other problem, it seems that since my diagrams are `htmlwidget` objects and this seems to run into other kinds of issues probably out of the scope of my original question.

Comment: Here is an example to add to the markdown
` ```{r diagram, echo=FALSE}
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("digraph {
          node [shape = circle]
          a, b
          edge[color=grey]
          a -> b}")
``` `

Comment: @Warner Since the result generated from `DiagrammeR` is `htmlwidget`, so a possible solution is to modify the `inline_render` function, so the output is `html_document` instead of `md_document`, and also `cat(join(readLines(paste0(script_name, ".html")), "\n"))` instead of `cat(join(readLines(paste0(script_name, ".md")), "\n"))`. Then it seems to work.

Comment: Yes this worked for me! Thanks a lot for helping me out with this!