# Add an equation using roxygen2 in Rscript

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, equation, roxygen2

I am using functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831888/rendering-multiple-r-scripts-as-markdown-within-single-markdown-file) to render multiple independent `R` scripts in a single markdown files. But I am not able to include a formatted equation in those scripts. My `.Rmd` file looks like:

````
--- 
title: "My title"
author: "Nacho"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: rmdformats::downcute
--- 

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

join <- function(ls, sep = ", "){
do.call(paste, append(ls, list(sep = sep))) 
}

inline_render <- function(script_name){
suppressMessages(capture.output(rmarkdown::render(paste0(script_name, ".R"), 
output_format = "rmarkdown::md_document"), file = "tmp"))
cat(join(readLines(paste0(script_name, ".md")), "\n"))
}
```

Here is some text defining the scope of the analysis...

```{r script, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
inline_render("script")
```
````

And in my `script` I have defined an equation:

```
#'
#'  $$\frac{d_{A}}{dt} = K_{rel}\times A$$
#'
```

But when this `.R` is rendered to `.md`, I get this warning:

> [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math \frac{A}{dt} = K_{rel}\times A, rendering as TeX

and this is what is what I find in the `.md`

```
$$\\frac{d\_{DXD}}{dt} = K\_{rel}\\times A\_{T-DXd}$$
```

So, when this is rendered to the final `.html` I just the plain text ignoring all `\*`.

I tried to edit the intermediate `.md` file to remove one of the `\` but the one remaining seems to be ignored by the `cat()` call.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is an extra curly brace `}` at the end of your math formula.

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent, that was a typo in the post, but not in my actual code.

Comment: I'm currently puzzling over a (possibly similar) problem when trying to include $\sqrt{x}$ in the github-hosted README of my RStudio project.  Possibly relevant:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775941/rstudio-readme-rmd-and-readme-md-should-be-both-staged-use-git-commit-no-veri


https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/news/index.html#rmarkdown-217 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313094/pandoc-warning-could-not-convert-tex-math/74935912#74935912.  This/that; esto/eso/aquello; “When I use a word… it means just what I choose it to mean – neither more nor less.”