# Include specific slides from another presentation for Xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I use `xaringan` R package for making presentations.

I have following directory structure

```
└── presentations
    ├── 01_intro
    |    ├── intro.Rmd
    |    └── intro.html
    └── 02_test
    |    ├── test.Rmd
    |    └── test.html
    └── 03_new
         ├── new.Rmd
         └── new.html
```

For the new presentation (**03_new**), I would like to include slide number 3 from the intro slide (**01_intro**).

This could be done by:

1. `<iframe src="../01_intro/intro.html#3"></iframe>` or,
2. `knitr::include_url("../01_intro/intro.html#3")`

## Question

Is there a way to do that using `{r child='../01_intro/intro.Rmd{slide#}'}`?

OR

Is there a way to do that using `{r child='../01_intro/intro.Rmd{slide-name}'}`?

### Reasons I need a solution for this:

1. Easy to reuse, and I have a track of slides.
2. This would prevent me to work again on the same material.

This would be very beneficial when I have to make a new presentation from a number of existing presentations. I just input a specific section into a new one, then copy-paste or screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this question, I hope it helps, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output)

I think you are right about how you can go about it, just make the presentation slide it's own .RMD file, hopefully that doesn't get too confusing

````
 ---  
 title: My Report  
 output: 
   pdf_document:
     toc: yes 
 ---

 ```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
 ```

 ```{r child = 'chapter2.Rmd'}
 ```
````

Comment: I would like to avoid that. I have updated my question with reasons.