# How to share Rmd files between different bookdown projects?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I'd like to make multiple bookdown projects that have particular chapters in common. For example I would like the content of a particular file content_in_common.Rmd to be merged in to two different books when they are built. How can I achieve this? I understand that bookdown requires the Rmd files to be in a common working directory, so having

```
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "path_where_common_content_is_stored/content_in_common.Rmd"]
```

in my `_bookdown.yml` doesn't work because it returns

```
Error: Input files not all in same directory, please supply explicit wd
Execution halted
```

Is there a solution to this (short of manually making duplicate versions of content_in_common.Rmd)?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output) that suggests you can use
`{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}`

such as

````
---  
title: My Report  
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes 
---

```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'chapter2.Rmd'}
```
````

To use other .Rmd files inside your bookdown project hopefully