# How to combine multiple Weave.jl (.jmd) files into a single output?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to split a document in multiple .jmd files. Something similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output).
Basically what I'm trying to find out is what is the equivalent to R Markdown's child cells in Weave.jl.

An example of what I'm trying to obtain is a pdf obtained from combining three (or more) .jmd files:
**notes.jmd**

````
---
title: ...
author: ...
date: ...
---
```julia, child="chapter01.jmd"
```
```julia, child="chapter02.jmd"
```
````

**chapter01.jmd**

````
# Chapter 1 title
```julia
#= code here =#
```
````

**chapter02.jmd**

````
# Chapter 2 title

```julia
#= code here =#
```
````